# how to create a progress bar using php output buffering and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, progress, ob-start

how to create a progress bar using php output buffering  and jquery?

i been searching this for weeks,

i am desperate to learn this, this is a very big help for me, is someone the here share some codes?

i know the this will need to script.
i have tried sereval code for my client side script:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);

function updateProgress(e) {
var percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
 /** update the with of the progress bar **/
}
```

and to my server side, i dont know how. but actually i want to use this for a mysql query so that i can see the progress of my query and another thing is i dont know how to use output buffering.

somebody help me on this please.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to achieve this

1) Use PHP APC,iframe,Jquery

2) Flash file

3) CGI script

You can try first two, here is article for second method which give you more clarity

http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/test.php

below article for first method, but first method you need to configure PHP APC on your server it's like output buffering

http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/